# Replace or remove period/dot from expression

Tags: regex

I have this expression in PCRE and I want to leave/remove the . (period) out of klantnummer.

Expression:

```
^h:\/Klant\/(?<klantnummer>[^\/]+)\/(?<folder1>[^\/]+)\/(?<folder2>[^\/]+)
```

Input:

```
h:/Klant/12345678.9/map 1/map 2
```

Outcome: `12345678.9`

Desired result: `123456789`

https://regex101.com/r/EVv47V/1

So Klantnummer should have `123456789` as result

Comment: Can't you run a 2nd line to simply remove the dot from the result under the 'Klantnummer'? Or just remove the dot prior to your expression `^h:\/Klant\/\d+\K\.`, Or when there can be multiple dots, something like [`(?:^h:\/Klant\/\d+|\G(?!^))\d*\K\.`](https://regex101.com/r/s93vaO/1)

Comment: Is it used in splunk?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer JvdV! I'm new to regex and using it as input in other code. So I have only worked with a single line expression and don't know (yet) how to do this (use more lines).

Comment: If it's input to other coding than surely it will support functions to remove a dot from this particular input.

Comment: Not used in splunk Wiktor.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in one step. You could catch it in two Capture Groups:

```regex
^h:\/Klant\/(?<klantnummer1>[^\.\/]+)\.(?<klantnummer2>[^\/]+)\/(?<folder1>[^\/]+)\/(?<folder2>[^\/]+)
```

and put both together by string concatenation after or use two regex steps and filter out the period in the second, like stated in comments.

Regex above assumes there is always a period, this will work for 0 or 1 period in the number:

```regex
h:\/Klant\/(?<klantnummer1>[^\.\/]+)(?:\.?(?<klantnummer2>[^\.\/]+))\/(?<folder1>[^\/]+)\/(?<folder2>[^\/]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

As already discussed you can't do this on one step.
The solution of using 2 regex stages, or 2 splitting klantnummer into 2 groups before and after the capture group will both work.
However I believe that the simplest and most efficient both in terms of computer power and of code to write, will be to replace `.`with and empty String `''` after the regex, and before using it.
You haven't said which programming language you are using so I can't give you the syntax/example.
If all that you are doing is splitting the String on the slashes you will probably find it easier to split the string into an array.
For example in python

```py
s = "h:/Klant/12345678.9/map 1/map 2"
array = s.split('/')
Klantnummer=array[2].replace('.','')
folder1=array[3]
folder2=array[4]
print(Klantnummer)
print(folder1)
print(folder2)
```

output

```
123456789
map 1
map 2
```

Tested on https://www.online-python.com/